# Search multidimensional jsonb data in laravel postgres

Tags: php, json, postgresql, laravel-5, multidimensional-array

I have multiple `jsonb` data fields in my `postgres` database. Like my `Contacts` table has `name, addresses, phones and emails` as jsonb data fields. Most of the `jsonb` data fields are multidimensional. Like `emails` field have different json data for different email types. Following is the sample emails data i have in my database.

```
[
    {"tag": "Home", "value": "foo@bar.com"}, 
    {"tag": "Other", "value": "john@doe.net"}, 
    {"tag": "Work", "value": "john@foo.com"}, 
    {"tag": "Home", "value": "foo@gmail.com"}
]
```

I want to execute a search on emails field's value data. Like i want to fetch all the contacts with email `john@doe.net` in emails field.

I have tried to fetch the contacts with normal where query like

```
$contacts = Contact::where('emails->value', 'ilike', "%$query%")->get();
```

But it does not return anything and that is obvious because emails field is multidimensional. ***Although on a single dimensional json data this query works fine.***

What is the proper way of searching such data fields in `laravel eloquent` ?. It will be better if it can be done ***without using `whereRaw` with `jsonb_exists` function.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working and posting the answer here if in case anyone needs help in future.

Basically we can do a simple `where` query with `@>` operator. And the value can be json encoded with the searched email. Following is the query to search for particular email without using `whereRaw` method.

```
$contacts = Contact::where("emails", '@>', '[' . json_encode(['value' => $query]) . ']')->get();
```

Hope it helps some one else in future :)

Comment: I have the same formatted JSON. But it still returns nothing,I queried like this..... MeetingInvitee::where("apartments", '@>', '[' . json_encode(['flat_no' => 'A1']) . ']')->get()